# log4j:ERROR Could not parse file

Tags: java, maven, log4j, filenotfoundexception

I waste a lot of time to solve this problem. but can't. may be it is simple.

The jar file of application cant load the log4j.xml file which is the configuration file of log4j.
Here is the code i am using

```
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
public class LoggerConfig {
    public void configLogger()
    {
        DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
    }
}
```

Its a maven project. and my dir strucure is:

```
src
  main
    java
    |  com
    |  |  my
    |  |  |  abc
    |  |  |  |  test
    |  |  |  |  |  LoggerConfig.java
    resource
    |   com
    |   |  my 
    |   |  |  abc
    |   |  |  |  test
    |   |  |  |  |  log4j.xml
```

My classpath file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>  
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

My log4j.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
  <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="target/test.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="false" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] [%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] [%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Thanks for any help..

Comment: What does you `log4j.xml` look like?

Comment: @Tichodroma: Edited the question with `log4j.xml` details

Comment: Any specific reason you place your log4j.xml file under `com/my/abc/test` in `resources` Also when you load it you load it using `test/log4j.xml` whereas it should then be `com/my/abc/test/log4j.xml`?

Comment: @Kal : I edited it in question. Actually I used all the case. non of it works. when i put the jar in a different folder and run it from there it won't works. I changed the file name like `com/my/abc.test/log4j.xml` ,`log4j.xml`,etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [DOMConfigurator](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.java#595) code the argument passed to it is treated as a File name. Instead of that try using the classpath resource

```java
  public void configLogger()
    {
        URL u = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/my/abc/test/log4j.xml");
        DOMConfigurator.configure(u);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the exception in the following way. So you can try it for your project maybe it helps you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wtni.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).